# Get Component by Id between Components Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Is it possible to get another component by id inside a sibling component?
Example:

```
<paper-progress id="progress" value="10" indeterminate></paper-progress>

<my-iron-ajax url="http://someurl.com" auto last-response="{{data}}" stop-progress="progress"></my-iron-ajax>
```

The purpose is that when the ajax finish, stop the progress automatically. The final user of the component does not need to put JavaScript to stop the progress.

I already tried but without success.

The replication of the bug:
https://jsbin.com/sadahupixo/edit?html,output

Comment: Can you post your Polymer 2.0 code ?
Also it's possible to use the same polygit cdn for Polymer 2.0. See this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kigokeg/edit?html,output)

Comment: Yes, but in your jsbin. Your component declaration is the older version. The new on is creating a class. Now i know that have the 2.0 on cdn I will recreate the bug.

Comment: @Ümit I already replicate the bug. Is in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function to stop the Progress within your element.

Something like

```
    stopProgress() {
      this.$.progress.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

then you can just call from everywhere

```
document.getElementById('myID').stopProgress();
```

Remember you "can" only select elements within the "light" dom. The shadom dom is part of the element and should only be modified by the element itself.

For a working example see
https://jsbin.com/haguwoqote/edit?html,console,output

PS: doing only css changes could also be archived by using css variables only; but I would not recommend it in that case.